# Searching a string for an exact match from a list in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm working on a project that searches specific user's Twitter streams from my followers list and retweets them. The code below works fine, but if the string appears in side of the word (for instance if the desired string was only "man" but they wrote "manager", it'd get retweeted). I'm still pretty new to python, but my hunch is RegEx will be the way to go, but my attempts have proved useless thus far.

```
    if tweet["user"]["screen_name"] in friends: 
        for phrase in list:
                if phrase in tweet["text"].lower():
                    print tweet
                    api.retweet(tweet["id"])
                    return True
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want to match whole words the easiest way to get Python to do this is to split the tweet text into a list of words and then test for the presence of each of your words using `in`.

There's an optimization you can use because position isn't important: by building a set from the word list you make searching much faster (technically, O(1) rather than O(n)) because of the fast hashed access used by sets and dicts (thank you Tim Peters, also author of *The Zen of Python*).

The full solution is:

```
if tweet["user"]["screen_name"] in friends:
    tweet_words = set(tweet["text"].lower().split())
    for phrase in list:
        if phrase in tweet_words:
            print tweet
            api.retweet(tweet["id"])
            return True
```

This is not a complete solution. Really you should be taking care of things like purging leading and trailing punctuation. You could write a function to do that, and call it with the tweet text as an argument instead of using a `.split()` method call.

Given that optimization it occurred to me that iteration in Python could be avoided altogether if the phrases were a set also (the iteration will still happen, but at C speeds rather than Python speeds). So in the code that follows let's suppose that you have during initialization executed the code

```
tweet_words = set(l.lower() for l in list)
```

By the way, `list` is a terrible name for a variable, since by using it you make the Python list type unavailable under its usual name (though you can still get at it with tricks like `type([])`). Perhaps better to call it `word_list` or something else both more meaningful and not an existing name. You will have to adapt this code to your needs, it's just to give you the idea. Note that `tweet_words` only has to be set once.

```
list = ['Python', 'Perl', 'COBOL']
tweets = [
    "This vacation just isn't worth the bother",
    "Goodness me she's a great Perl programmer",
    "This one slides by under the radar",
    "I used to program COBOL but I'm all right now",
    "A visit to the doctor is not reported"
]
tweet_words = set(w.lower() for w in list)
for tweet in tweets:
    if set(tweet.lower().split()) & tweet_words:
        print(tweet)
```

Comment: That's a really good solution, thanks! For what it's worth, list wasn't the actual variable name (I just used it as a dummy variable for my own reading ease)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regexes to do this, look for a pattern that is of the form `\b<string>\b`. In your case this would be:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\bman\b")
if re.search(pattern, tweet["text"].lower()):
    #do your thing
```

`\b` looks for a word boundary in regex. So prefixing and suffixing your pattern with it will match only the pattern. Hope it helps.

Comment: You should change to `r"\bman\b"`.  What you have now will not give what you expect.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using pattern = re.compile(r'\b' +phrase+ r'\b') and it appears to be working. After some very unfortunate twitter retweet matches today (I was searching Members of Congress' tweets for rape and it pulled in grape). Thanks, again! Check out the app on @SexualCongress sometime.